# Need help refactoring a Global Variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, refactoring, global

I have a recipe script with some PHP code that was written with Global Variables.  Would anyone be able to tell me a general process (or order of operations so-to-speak) that I could follow to begin swapping out the global variables?  Here's an example:

```
function computeCost() {
  global $DB_LINK;
  $this->loadIngred();

  if ($this->liquid == $DB_LINK->true)
    $liquid = true;
  $amount = Units::convertTo($this->amount, $this->unitMapping, $this->unit, 
    $this->liquid);
  return ($this->amount * $this->cost);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a global variable you could pass it into the function like this:

```
function computeCost($db_link) {
```

And call the function like this:

```
$returnValue = computeCost($DB_LINK);
```

This way, no Globals are needed (and this is better) and you pass the data into the function. So the function does not have a dependency with the outside, as it is supposed to be.